# Spark Scala - Apply ML/Complex functions on a GroupBy DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib

I have a large DataFrame (Spark 1.6 Scala) which looks like this:

```
Type,Value1,Value2,Value3,...
--------------------------
A,11.4,2,3
A,82.0,1,2
A,53.8,3,4
B,31.0,4,5
B,22.6,5,6
B,43.1,6,7
B,11.0,7,8
C,22.1,8,9
C,3.2,9,1
C,13.1,2,3
```

From this I want to group by Type and apply machine learning algorithms and/or perform complex functions on each group.
My objective is perform complex functions on each group in parallel.

I have tried the following approaches:

Approach 1) Convert Dataframe to Dataset and then use `ds.mapGroups()` api. But this is giving me an Iterator of each group values.
If i want to perform `RandomForestClassificationModel.transform(dataset: DataFrame)`, i need a DataFrame with only a particular group values.
I was not sure converting Iterator to a Dataframe within mapGroups is a good idea.

Approach 2) Distinct on Type, then map on them and then filter for each Type with in the map loop:

```
val types = df.select("Type").distinct()
val ff = types.map(row => {
  val type = row.getString(0)    
  val thisGroupDF = df.filter(col("Type") == type)
  // Apply complex functions on thisGroupDF    
  (type, predictedValue)
})
```

For some reason, the above is never completing (seems to be getting into some kind of infinite loop)

Approach 3) Exploring Window functions, but did not find a method which can provide dataframe of particular group values.

Please help.

Comment: Hi
I have some suggestions regarding the Approach #2.
Here you are operating on a Dataframe inside the map function for a Dataframe. I doubt that could be done. I checked it on my system, and it failed.

To avoid this, you should do a collect on types, to get it in a local object and perform the map operation on that:
`val types = df.select("Type").distinct().collect()`

This should work.

Also you would have to use a "===" operator for filter operation instead of "==".